# Developing on linux kernel with Eclipse

Tags: linux, eclipse, linux-kernel

I am following a guide to help me setup a kernel in Eclipse: [link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/HowTo_use_the_CDT_to_navigate_Linux_kernel_source)
On step 24 it asks me to add include/uapi directories but I don't seem to have that directory in the kernel I am working with; in fact, a general search says I have no folder named uapi inside the kernel. This made me wonder what these uapi directories are and why I don't have them?

Working with an old kernel btw: 2.6.35.14

Comment: That old kernel did not have uapi separated. You can just ignore that step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`include/uapi` folder was added only in `v3.7-rc1`**

`uapi` is intended to be copied to an installation as part of the user-accessible kernel headers. Depends on linux distro, some of these headers are copied to `/usr/include/linux/` . But this is not part of the default install, it is actually separated in a different package: `linux-api-headers`.

There is no `/usr/include/uapi` (for example on my ubuntu 16.04 it is empty) and this is by design, the contents of the original `uapi` folder are directly copied into `/usr/include`

So you can skip this step.

---

A little bit of history and interesting information regard UAPI:

The UAPI patchset was motivated by David David Howell's observation that when modifying the kernel code:

> I occasionally run into a problem where I can't write an inline
>   function in a header file because I need to access something from
>   another header that includes this one. Due to this, I end up writing
>   it as a #define instead.

He went on to elaborate that this problem of "inclusion recursion" in header files typically occurs with inline functions:

> Quite often it's a case of an inline function in header A wanting a
>   struct [or constant or whatever] from header B, but header B already
>   has an inline function that wants a struct from header A.

The main idea was to split out the user-space API content of the kernel header files in the `include` and `arch/xxxxxx/include` directories, placing that content into corresponding headers created in new `uapi/ subdirectories` that reside under each of the original directories. It simplifies and reduces the size of the kernel-only headers. More importantly, splitting out the user-space APIs into separate headers has the desirable consequence that it `"simplifies the complex interdependencies between headers that are [currently] partly exported to userspace".`

There is one other benefit of the UAPI split that may be of particular interest to the wider Linux ecosystem. By placing all of the user-space API-related definitions into files dedicated solely to that task, it becomes easier to track changes to the APIs that the kernel presents to user space.